# Running Chrome ignoring Cross-Origin Chrome policy

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, security, web, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run `Chrome` using `selenium webdriver` without any security restrictions as part of an experiment.
Basically, I'm trying to access `iframe` context from different origin then my page.

Obviously, by default I'm getting the Cross-Origin exception - that's what I want to avoid and I know that I can achieve that using a `browser extension`, but I want to find alternatives.

Exception that I get when trying to access iframe context:

> DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I've tried to set any of suggested flags that I found online and official documentation when running `Chrome/Chromium`:

```
      '--allow-file-access-from-files',
      '--system-developer-mode',
      '-–allow-file-access-from-files',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--user-data-dir=/home/chrome-dir',
      '--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating'
```

My html page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script that I'm injecting:

```
for (let i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
  try {
    const frame = window.frames[i];
    console.log(frame.name, frame.document);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

My webdriver code:

```
const { Builder, Capabilities } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const fs = require('fs');

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function constructChromeOptions() {
  const options = {
    'args': [
      '--allow-file-access-from-files',
      '--system-developer-mode',
      '--force-dev-mode-highlighting',
      '-–allow-file-access-from-files',
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--user-data-dir=/home/chrome-dir',
    ]
  };
  return options;
}

function constructChromeCapabilities(packedExtensionPath) {
  const chromeCapabilities = Capabilities.chrome();
  const chromeOptions = constructChromeOptions(packedExtensionPath);
  const capabilities = chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
  return capabilities;
}

(async function init() {
    let driver = await new Builder()
      .withCapabilities(constructChromeCapabilities())
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .build();
    await driver.get(`file:///${__dirname}/iframes.html`);
    const js = fs.readFileSync('scripts/inject.bundle.js', 'utf8');
    driver.executeScript(js);
}();
```